# R Comparison of two variables to avoid duplication

Tags: r, variables, dataframe

I have this dataframe

```
`> str(AMComp)
'data.frame':   1300697 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Commodity.Code       : chr  "H0-842481" "H0-842481" "H0-842481" "H0-842481" ...
 $ Commodity.Description: chr  "Agricultural sprays and powder dispersers" "Agricultural sprays and powder dispersers" "Agricultural sprays and powder dispersers" "Agricultural sprays and powder dispersers" ...
 $ Period               : int  1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 1988 ...
 $ Reporter             : chr  "Australia" "Australia" "Australia" "Australia" ...
 $ Partner              : chr  "Areas, nes" "Argentina" "Austria" "Brazil" ...
 $ Value.Import         : num  156 NA 425739 16623 6930 ...
 $ Value.Export         : num  NA 3025 NA NA 70355 ...
 $ Trade.Difference     : num  NA NA NA NA -63425 ...`
```

I have noticed that in the variable `Reporter` and in the variable `Partner` there are some inconsistencies. For instance some `Reporter`s claim to have imported or exported things to itself.

Now, I have to get rid of those inconsistencies. All cases in which the variable `Reporter` and  the variable `Partner` coincide should be flagged in order to eventually delete those observations.

Comment: Maybe `AMComp <- AMComp[AMComp$Reporter != AMComp$Partner, ]` ?

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a simple flag that's 1 when Reporter is equal to Partner and 0 otherwise:

```
AMComp$flag <- ifelse(AMComp$Reporter == AMComp$Partner, 1,0)
```

If you want to eliminate the problematic entries you can then simply do:

```
AMComp_clean <- AMComp[AMComp$flag == 0,]
```

Where `AMComp_clean` is the new cleaned dataframe.

Comment: No problem, if you are happy with the  answer, can you mark it as correct?  ;)